# Does StarCraft 2 have cheat codes?

Tags: starcraft-2, cheats

Does StarCraft 2 feature cheat codes? If so do codes vary between Wings of Liberty and Heart of the Swarm? Are there penalties for using cheat codes?

Possible examples:

- God mode
- Unlock entire tech tree
- Infinite resources
- Infinite pool

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure if cheat codes vary between WoL and HoTS, but on the StarCraft 2 blog in December 2010 Blizzard admitted to there being [cheats in StarCraft 2](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/blog/1316152):

> Cheat codes can only be used in single-player mode by pressing the
>   enter key within the game and typing in the codes as shown below
>   within the console.
>
> **Caution**: Before using cheat codes it’s important to understand that
>   using them will prevent additional achievement gains you might have
>   earned through normal play until either a new campaign is started or a
>   prior save is loaded (one from before the use of the first cheat).

A similar list of [Heart of the Swarm cheats can be found on IGN](http://www.ign.com/cheats/games/starcraft-ii-heart-of-the-swarm-pc-14289205) so it does appear that there is some overlap.

Answer (score 6):

Some are exclusive to WoL or HoTS, but in general almost all of them work in both and the only bad thing is that they are not compatible with achievements (i.e. most of them will disable achievements when used).

- God mode: `TerribleTerribleDamage`
- Instant victory: `WhatIsBestInLife`
- Instant defeat: `LetsJustBugOutAndCallItEven`
- Disable fog of war: `TookTheRedPill`
- Disable the need for supplies: `Bunker55AliveInside`
- Gain 5000 minerals: `SpectralTiger`
- Gain 5000 gas: `RealMenDrillDeep`
- Gain 5000 of each resource: `WhoRunBartertown`
- Allow the use of all tech: `SoSayWeAll`
- Upgrade weapons, armor, and shields by a level: `IAmIronMan`
- Enable fast builds and fast upgrades: `CatFoodForPrawnGuns`
- Disable cooldowns on spells: `HanShotFirst`
- Disable victory conditions for continued play: `TyuHasLeftTheGame`
- Continued play after defeat: `NeverGiveUpNeverSurrender`
- Fast unit healing: `ImADoctorNotARoachJim`
- All units and buildings are free: `MoreDotsMoreDots`
- Add 5 million credits in story mode: `WhySoSerious` (Only for Wings of Liberty campaign)
- Unlock all missions: `LeaveYourSleep`
- Unlock all cinematics: `EyeOfSauron`
- Unlock all UNN TV news broadcasts: `StayClassyMarSara` (Doesn't work in Heart of the Swarm)
- In custom maps add 5000 Terrazine: `Jaynestown`
- Play the song Terran Up the Night: `OverEngineeredCodPiece` (This doesn't disable achievements)

Source: [Mejoress](https://www.mejoress.com/en/starcraft-2-cheats-codes/)