# Why did I not get achievement for completing the mission?

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

I just completed the mission Fire in the sky, why did I not receive the achievement for doing this?

[image: Screenshot of the Victory! screen for Fire in the Sky - Hard; shows the hover for the "Fire in the Sky" achievement: 'Complete the "Fire in the Sky" mission in the Heart of the Swarm campaign.'; the achievement is grayed out]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you lose your connection to battle.net for more than a minute or so, Achievements are automatically disabled, and do not get re-enabled for the duration of the mission, even if you subsequently reconnect.

There is a pop-up on-screen that mentions this, but it's easily missed, especially if you are in the middle of directing a pitched fight.

If you have a save near the end of the mission, you can try reloading it, though there's no in-game way to check whether or not achievements have been disabled for the current map. A more provable solution would be to replay the mission from the start. Even if your internet is fine and dandy, it's not impossible Blizzard has been experiencing some launch-day network hiccups.

Another alternative (that I don't think applies to your case) is that you used some of the [single-player cheat codes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/108427/559), which will also permanently disable achievements for the current campaign.

Comment: Gggrrr your answer is the faster gun. :)

Comment: @ahsteele he's the faster when there is a competition going on... =P

Answer (score 5):

Probably **server fault** since it is first day of game release and they are under a lot of stress.Give it some time it may still appear on your list since it may just be very s**low server response**.

Or you might have just **lost your internet connection** at the wrong time.

Some people really had bad luck with this sort of thing [link](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=139700)

Personally just a few moments ago when i logged to my SC account,my achievements were not loading at all like I haven't completed any of the...But my progress and other things were fine.

Answer (score 2):

You may have been the victim of a glitch in the achievements server today. Blizzard announced that they are looking into an issue that is disconnecting players, preventing achievements and experience gain.

Forum post [here](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/8197910849).