# How can I earn the level 70 Kerrigan Power achievement if I wasn't awarded it?

Tags: starcraft-2

Like [Blem indicates in his comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108824/do-i-get-kerrigan-levels-if-i-replay-a-mission#comment146348_108839) when Kerrigan reached level 70 I did not get Kerrigan Power achievement. I was **connected to the internet** at the time of the level up and **have not used any [cheat codes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/108427/559)**.

Do I need to replay the campaign to earn the achievement? Is there a reason the achievement wouldn't have been earned even though Kerrigan has reached level to 70?

Comment: I had it listed in my answer, but took it away due to Blem's comment. I think, afterall, the fact that it's not being unlocked is due to a bug.

Comment: They even added a separate line for Kerrigan Power Achievement not granting through the Archives on the known issues list I linked in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recently Blizzard released patch for those who earned level 70 for Kerrigan but didn't get the achievement. That will require re-enterring storey mode or Master Archives. They also promised to enhance bug-fix even more.

> The Story Mode achievement Kerrigan Power: 70 is now awarded upon
>   re-entering story mode or the Master Archives for players who
>   previously reached Kerrigan level 70. (An additional component to this
>   fix will be applied in a future patch, which will properly grant
>   credit immediately upon fulfilling achievement requirements.)

Read in full here: http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/blog/9096527/

Answer (score 10):

The Kerrigan Power achievements (and quite a few other Kerrigan Achievements) are currently [bugged](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/2267599524) (scroll down to Heart Campaign).  The level 70 achievement will not be granted if you get the final levels from the archive.

Workaround if you have a save game from the Conviction mission(not the Archive).

1. Load the mission and quit it, this resets the campaign back to that point of the game.
2. Go to the Archives.
3. Complete any missed objectives to get Kerrigan to level 59.
4. Once you complete all of the Kerrigan levels, exit out of the Archives and go back to the Leviathan.
5. Start the mission Conviction.
6. Finish the bonus objectives within the level and complete it.

Answer (score 3):

Blizzard disabled achievements for a while on launch day.

You can see several threads about it on battle.net (there's one [here](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/8197180681), for example). The devs have indicated that they shouldn't be disabled any more ([here](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/8197180684?page=11#214)) but that doesn't help much for achievements you should have unlocked while they were disabled.

See my question [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108989/how-can-i-earn-achievements-i-got-while-achievements-were-disabled) about how to get achievements that should have unlocked while they were disabled.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you were disconnected from the achievement servers temporarily while maintaining an internet connection, or earned it while [the achievement servers were down](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/8197910849).

Either way, it sounds like the achievement is triggered by a level change, and my guess is that unless you get her to level 70 again, you'll need to wait for a Blizzard response, as happened in the Blacksmith/Jeweller achievements in Diablo III.

Comment: While this sounds plausible, I am not sure the bit about the level change is correct, since I went back and got bonus objectives (for missing Kerrigan levels) before assaulting Korhal (3 level changes). I did 3 missions on Korhal at level 70 but was not awarded this achievement.

Comment: doesnt work... was level 65 and played conviction with all bonus aims... nothing happens